# How do I make it so that every line of a text widget has a double space in the beginning no matter what else gets inserted in it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a restaurant menu in python using tkinter and I noticed that my menu items are too close to the edge of the text widget. How do I make it so that every line has some space at the start?

Relevant code:

```
items = tk.Text(bg = 'black',font = ('Baskerville', 18),wrap = tk.WORD,height = 20,)
items.grid(column = 0,row = 2, columnspan = 4,padx = 15,pady = 10)


# Print Menu Items
def printItems(course):
    global exportCourse
    exportCourse = course
    items.config(state='normal')

    # Adjust Menu Items According To Dietary Preferences
    query = 'Select Item,Price,Description FROM {} where Item is Not Null'
    if vegan_choice_intvar.get() == 1:
        query += ' and Vegan = "Yes"'
    if veg_choice_intvar.get() == 1:
        query += ' and Vegetarian = "Yes"'
    if soy_choice_intvar.get() == 1:
        query += ' and ContainsSoy = "No"'
    if nuts_choice_intvar.get() == 1:
        query += ' and ContainsNuts = "No"'
    if milk_choice_intvar.get() == 1:
        query += ' and ContainsMilk = "No"'
    if fish_choice_intvar.get() == 1:
        query += ' and ContainsFish = "No"'
        
    # Retrieve Item Count
    cur.execute("select count(Item) from {}".format("Menu" + course))
    n = cur.fetchone()[0]

    #Check If List Is Empty
    if n == 0:
        items.delete(1.0,'end')
        items.insert(tk.END,'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n                                                        No Items Here')
        items.config(state='disabled',highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground='white',highlightcolor='white')
        return

    # Retrieve Item Details
    cur.execute(query.format('Menu' + course))

    # Assemble Details And Print
    items.config(state = 'normal')
    items.delete(1.0,'end')
    for i in range(1,n + 1):
        result = cur.fetchone()
        items.insert(tk.END,'\n\n' + str(i) + ". " + result[0] + ' (' + str(result[1]) + '$)' + '\n' + result[2])
    items.config(state='disabled',highlightthickness=2,highlightcolor='white',highlightbackground='white')
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: Convert from `items.insert(tk.END,'\n\n' ...)` to `items.insert(tk.END,'\n\n  ' ...)` this. Added two spaces.

Comment: That only makes the item name have the space. The Item descriptions (the one below the names) need the space as well. There's another problem that if the description's big enough that that it takes up more than one line, those lines need the space as well. That's why I'm trying to have the space on every single line in the widget.

Comment: Try setting `spacing1` (space before each line) and `spacing2` (space between wrapped lines) options of `Text` widget.  See [document](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M13).

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks! Unfortunately, those only seem to leave the space above the line and not infront of it.

Comment: Then use `items.tag_config("lmargin", lmargin1=20, lmargin2=20)` to add some spacing at the left side of each line.  Specify the tag "lmargin" when inserting lines: `items.insert(tk.END, "...", "lmargin")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some *margin* at the left side of the text box, you can use `.tag_config()` to set up the margins and add the tag in every `.insert()`:

```py
...
# setup margins using tag "lmargins"
items.tag_config("lmargins", lmargin1=20, lmargin2=20)

def printItems(course):
    ...
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        ...
        # add the tag "lmargins"
        items.insert(tk.END, '\n\n'+str(i)+". "+result[0]+' ('+str(result[1])+'$)'+'\n'+result[2], "lmargins")
    ...
```

Sample result:

[image]